# How to show that a given line has a certain equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Say line $A(3,0)$ and $B(0,2)$

How do I 'show' that they have equation $2x + 3y - 6 = 0$?

Comment: Plug the numbers in and see if you have an equality.

Comment: Substitute to the equation. See if they satisfy it. then use one of the oldest axioms in the history of mathematics - "There is one and only one line between two distinct points".

Answer (score 1):

In two dimensional geometry, the equation of a line $(AB)$ where $x_A\not=x_B$ is $$y-y_B=\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\left(x-x_A\right)$$
Just replace $x_A$, $x_B$, $y_A$ and $y_B$ by their values.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: USE this

$$\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}$$

Comment: I find it easier remember it as follows
$$m=m$$
$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
$$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_2}$$